# Super Simple JQuery Complication ... Need insight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help me understand the problem in this code. I have tried multiple variations of it to no avail. I can make the code work in Chrome Console, but not hardcoded in. Please note that for my project, the structure of this line is essential:

```
<div class="asqFooter"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
```

Please do not modify the structure of `<div><a></a></div>` :)

The idea behind this code is to simulate a click on `<a>` anchor without a class and without an id. Due to this the `<a>` is wrapped in a `<div>` element. The code makes the div clickable, but it does not simulate a click to the `asqFooter` link.
Anyways so below is the simplified code version:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SimulateAskAQuestion() {
        $('.asqFooter a').click();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="SimulateAskAQuestion()"><div class="faX"><i class="fasize fa fa-question-circle-o fa-5x"></i><br>Ask a Question</div> </a>
 <div class="asqFooter"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
 </body>
```

Any ideas? I have also tried these variations:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:GetElementsByClassName('.asqFooter' a');">
<div class="faX"><i class="fasize fa fa-question-circle-o fa-5x"></i>  <br>Ask a Question</div> </a>
 <div class="asqFooter"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>
 </body>
```

and `<a href="javascript:SimulateAskQuestion();">`

Comment: If you're wondering why you can't link to google.com, that has to do with domain privileges. You can not link to another domain. Change `http://google.com` to `http://stackoverflow.com` in a code snippet on this site and it will work. Change it to `https://jsfiddle.net` and it will work on jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the parameter-less variant of the `click` method is equivalent to calling `trigger("click")` on the element. The `trigger` method only fires the appropriate event, it doesn't trigger navigation for anchor links. Instead of using the `click` method, you can use the `window.location` property in conjunction with jQuery's `attr` method to point the browser to the URL that the anchor tag points to.

```
function SimulateAskAQuestion() {
    window.location = $('.asqFooter a').attr("href");
}
```

[Here's a working example.](http://codepen.io/shadowfacts/pen/oYOJwL?editors=1010) (I've changed the URL of the anchor tag in the `.asqFooter` div so that the site will load properly inside the iframe, this should work normally with any other URL outside of the iframe.)

Answer (score 0):

Add `[0]` after the jQuery-object, for it to work: `$('.asqFooter a')[0].click();`

You need to access the actual DOM element for the `click` to work on an `a` tag.
The jQuery-object holds the actual DOM elements as properties with keys `0 - n`. Even if there's just one DOM element, that element is still wrapped inside the jQuery-object, at key `"0"`.
So using `$('.asqFooter a')[0].click();`, you'll perform the `click` on the first element in the jQuery-object:

```js
function SimulateAskAQuestion() {$('.asqFooter a')[0].click();}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="SimulateAskAQuestion()"><div class="faX"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o fa-5x"></i><br>Ask a Question</div></a>
<div class="asqFooter"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link</a></div>
```

This however, still only works after a **doubleclick**, this is because of the `href="#"`.
Without it, it works after a **singleclick**:

```js
function SimulateAskAQuestion() {$('.asqFooter a')[0].click();}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a onclick="SimulateAskAQuestion()"><div class="faX"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o fa-5x"></i><br>Ask a Question</div></a>
<div class="asqFooter"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link</a></div>
```

Of course, now that first `a`-tag is useless, so I would advice you to remove that `a` and style the `div` like an `a` using CSS (`a, .faX {...}` ensures that the `a` and the `div` have the same color):

```js
function SimulateAskAQuestion() {$('.asqFooter a')[0].click();}
```

```css
a, .faX {color:blue; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="faX" onclick="SimulateAskAQuestion()"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o fa-5x"></i><br>Ask a Question</div>
<div class="asqFooter"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link</a></div>
```

*(I changed the link because you can only link within the current domain)*